# Monotone class theorem - proof explanation

Tags: proof-explanation

I am studying the proof of the monotone class theorem in the book "Real analysis for graduate students" by Richard Bass, but I got stuck at a particular point.
[image: The theorem]

The idea behind the proof is clear to me, we want to define subsets ($\mathcal{N}_i)$ of $\mathcal{M}$ that have properties of $\sigma$-Algebras and then show that these subsets ($\mathcal{N}_i)$ are actually the same as $\mathcal{M}$. This would show that the smallest monotone class that contains $A_0$ is in fact a $\sigma$-Algebra.

Now here is where I get stuck. I do not understand the claim I underlined in red.
[image: Part of the proof]

$A_0$ is clearly a subset of $\mathcal{M}$. For each element $B_i$ in $A_0$, we know that $B_i^c$ is also in $A_0$, as $A_0$ is an algebra. But this is only for the elements IN $A_0$. How do we show that $A_0^c$ is an element in $\mathcal{M}$? (as this would imply that $A_0$ is in $\mathcal{N_1}$ by definition.)

Comment: So $A_0$ is **not** a $\sigma -$algabra but an algebra only. Now, if $A\in A_0\subset \mathcal M$, as you said, $A^c\in A_0\subset \mathcal M$. Therefore $\mathcal N_1\supset A_0$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the implication. The algebra $A_0$ itself is closed under complement and is contained in $\mathcal{M}$. But don't we have to show that the complement of the algebra $A_0$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: What is Bass' definition of a monotone class?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, a monotone class  $\mathcal{M}$ has 2 properties.
1. If a sequence of sets $A_i\textuparrow A$ and each $A_i\in \mathcal{M}$, then $A\in\mathcal{M}$.


2. If a sequence of sets $A_i\textdownarrow A$ and each $A_i\in \mathcal{M}$, then $A\in\mathcal{M}$. 

I do not see what you are trying to make figure out, it is probably something very trivial but I simply do not understand the implication as explained in my previous comment on Surb